# Can't use control from other project in xaml WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want use a control from another class

```
xmlns:control="clr-namespace:Devices;assembly=Devices"

 <Grid>
    <control:D_main VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

And this control

```
<UserControl x:Class="Devices.D_main"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Devices"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
   Height="704.667" Width="1173.833">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="611*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="563*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <local:DHControl x:Name="HControl" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
</Grid>
```

The class is public. All other controls I can use in this way, but with this I see an error.

> Exception: Cannot create an instance of "D_main".

StackTrace:

> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.InstanceBuilders.InstanceBuilderOperations.InstantiateType(Type type, Boolean supportInternal)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.InstantiateTargetType(ILocalInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.Instantiate(ILocalInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfDesigner.InstanceBuilders.FrameworkElementInstanceBuilder.Instantiate(ILocalInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfDesigner.InstanceBuilders.UserControlInstanceBuilder.Instantiate(ILocalInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.InstanceBuilders.LocalInstanceManager.CreateInstance(IInstanceBuilder builder, ViewNode viewNode)

When I hover over the control before build I see a message:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Can you show the code of the `D_main` control?

Comment: @thatguy I added

Comment: Have you checked if [any post with similar error](https://www.google.com/search?q=Exception:+Cannot+create+an+instance+of+site:stackoverflow.com) helps?

Comment: @Sinatr thanks you, problem is in constructor DFrameControl = new DFrame(HControl); I dont know how repair it yet, but know where is error.

Comment: What is DFrame? See [mcve].

Comment: It is Page and forwards its instance to other objects, but it is the default, thus causing errors.

Comment: Have you checked the dependencies of HControl and Dframe?  Do they perhaps use things in their constructors that you don't have in this project? As an aside. You should never have code like that in a ui element constructor. If it errors then nothing is constructed and you haven't got the piece of UI you expected. No UI often leads to catastrophic failures and bugs that are very difficult to trace.

Comment: @Andy still analyzes everything, it's not my code and the project is extensive. Thanks for adivce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question and the code you attached is a bit unclear. I can give you an example.
If you have a class (UserControl) like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="myProject.newUC"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="200">
    <Grid Background="Red">
            
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

You can use this class in a window like this:

```
<Window x:Class="myProject.MainWindow"        
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-myProject"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <local:newUC></local:newUC>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```